# Interaction between Leonin Warleader and Divine Visitation

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Divine Visitation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDivine%20Visitation%5d) on the battlefield:

> If one or more creature tokens would be created under your control, that many 4/4 white Angel creature tokens with flying and vigilance are created instead.

Then I play [Leonin Warleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeonin%20Warleader%5d):

> Whenever Leonin Warleader attacks, create two 1/1 white Cat creature tokens with lifelink that are tapped and attacking.

So the tokens will transfrom into 4/4 angles. But are they still tapped and attacking, or do the angles coming onto the battlefield negate the detail of "tapped and attacking"?

**In other words, does the enchantment place the angles instead of:**

1. "Cat creature tokens with lifelink", or
2. "Cat creature tokens with lifelink that are tapped and attacking"?

Comment: related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35348/does-doubling-season-creates-attacking-tokens-with-hanweir-garrison/35349#35349

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered in the rulings for Divine Visitation (emphasis mine):

> The token’s characteristics are entirely replaced by a 4/4 white Angel creature token with flying and vigilance. It doesn’t have any abilities the token would have been created with. **Anything else specified in the effect creating the token (such as tapped, attacking, “That token gains haste,” or “Exile that token at end of combat”) still applies**.

So you make two 4/4 Angel tokens that are tapped and attacking.

Comment: Yes, even though they have vigilance they will still be tapped.